# Shouldn't ILookup<TKey, TElement> be (declared) covariant in TElement?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, covariance

The definition `System.Linq.ILookUp<TKey, TElement>` reads

```cs
interface ILookup<TKey, TElement> : IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>, IEnumerable 
{
    int Count { get; }

    IEnumerable<TElement> this[TKey key] { get; }

    bool Contains(TKey key);
}
```

Since `IEnumerable` is covariant in `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` , `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` is covariant in `TElement` and the interface only exposes `TElement` as a return type, I would assume that `ILookup` is also covariant in `TElement`. Indeed, the definition

```cs
interface IMyLookup<TKey, out TElement> : IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>, IEnumerable 
{
    int Count { get; }

    IEnumerable<TElement> this[TKey key] { get; }

    bool Contains(TKey key);
}
```

compiles without problems.

So, what might be the reason why the **out** keyword is missing in the original definition? Might it be added future versions of Linq?

Comment: ...nobody thought of, designed, implemented, tested, released....or maybe an entirely different reason.

Comment: Well, I was just wondering whether that already is the whole story. On the other hand, I'm curious if such cases are a) common b) likely to be _fixed_ in the future

Comment: LINQ was introduced in .NET Framework 3.5 (C# 3.0), while variance for generic type parameters in interfaces since C# 4.0. Could this be the reason?

Comment: @A.Rodas Don't think so, `IEnumerable<T>` is now `IEnumerable<out T>` and it doesn't break backward compatibility.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: I'm almost sure I've heard that words (or very similar) somewhere else.. do you have by chance any ref to the origin?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, Eric Lippert has used that phrase on occasion. What can I say, it's been burned into my brain. Here's one of them. [Paragraph 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx).

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: "(..), documented and shipped" perfect match! I even remember reading that article. Thank you very much for the link!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tracking the MSDN documentation, [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) have been introduced in .NET Framework 4 Prior to that, there was `IEnumerable<T>` since the .NET Framework 2.0 up to .NET Framework 3.5. Then in .NET Framework 4.0 we can see `IEnumerable<out T>` with type parameter `T` as covariance.

`IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` and `ILookup<TKey, TElement>` have existed since .NET Framework 3.5. In .NET Framework 4.0 the former has been updated to `IGrouping<out TKey, out TElement>` but the latter has been omitted without specifying the reason.

`TKey` can't be covariant since implementations of `Contains(TKey)` and `this[TKey]` prevent that.

With regard to `TElement` the issue is not clear. I don't believe that designers just missed it. Perhaps cause lies in the plans for the future. Or they wanted to prevent something like the below, but I don't know why:

```
string[] strings = new[] {"a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c"};
ILookup<string, string> lookup = strings.ToLookup(s => s); // Valid.
ILookup<string, object> lookup = strings.ToLookup(s => s); // Now invalid, but would correct if TElement was covariant (out TElement).
```

There are also other authors, that pay attention to that issue:

[ToLookup](http://edulinq.googlecode.com/hg/posts/18-ToLookup.html):

> One slightly odd point to note is that while IGrouping is covariant in TKey and TElement, ILookup is invariant in both of its type parameters. While TKey has to be invariant, it would be reasonable for TElement to be covariant

Comment: Really nice answer, thanks. Even though this does not directly answer my question, your answer shows that there is an issue here (even if just a small). I've accepted your answer since that's probably all one can find out about the problem. +1 for finding the quote.

Comment: @bigge: Thank you for appreciating my time. I had the case in mind. If I find something new, I will add it to the answer.

Comment: When you say "prevent something like the below", what do you mean?  You specify that both `ToLookup` calls are legal (one "OK", and one "Legal").  What is the issue if everything works?

Comment: @PeterRitchie: _OK_ means _Legal for TElement_. The second is _Legal for out TElement_. I mean, that the latter would be valid if `TElement` is declarated as covariant i.e. `out TElement`. Thank you for your comment. I will write it more clearly.

Comment: can you please clarify what exactly you see invalid in `ILookup<string, object> lookup = strings.ToLookup(s => s); // Now invalid`?